# can someone explain from where in my console comes undefined value?

Tags: node.js

if i go to localhost:8080/?referal=referalID in my console i got referall id and also one line of undefined value, how can i remove that undefined line?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    var adr = req.url;
    var q = url.parse(adr, true);
    var qdata = q.query;

    res.end(console.log(qdata.referal));
}).listen(8080);
```

my question is what i need to change here?

Comment: There is only one `console.log` line here. What else can log to the console?

Comment: What are you hoping to happen, where is the value updefined, in the value sent back to the browser?

Comment: @user202729 in this case, HTTP logs & by console he probably means terminal. Post's owner, please provide screenshot or the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see `undefined` is because your browser is also looking for `favicon.ico` so your function gets hit twice. If you do:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    var adr = req.url;
    console.log(adr);
    var q = url.parse(adr, true);
    var qdata = q.query;
    res.end(qdata.referal);
}).listen(8080);
```

you will get:

> /?referal=referalID
>   /favicon.ico

The result of `url.parse('/favicon.ico', true);` is `undefined`.

Also as others mentioned `res.end(console.log(qdata.referal));` won't return anything to the browser/client because `console.log()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, however this should be the correct syntax:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  var adr;
  var q;
  var qdata;

  req.on('data', function() {
    // Data handler
  }).on('end', function() {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    adr = req.url;
    q = url.parse(adr, true);
    qdata = q.query;
    console.log(qdata);

    res.end(qdata.referal);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a `console.log` call in the response.

You should separate the two:

```
console.log(qdata.referal); // This will print in the console, server side
res.end(qdata.referal) // This will be echoed back to the client, in the browser
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined line you probably talking about is the one returns to the client, that's because console log doesn't return anything
as you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L127-L136)

Override console logging to return the arguments

```
['log', 'warn', 'error'].forEach(function(method) {
    var oldMethod = console[method].bind(console);
    console[method] = function() {
        oldMethod.apply(console, arguments);
        return arguments;
    };
});
```

Although this might save couple opcodes and pushing another object into the stack, you should use this with caution or memorize a pray that will help you with future-related-bugs.

Next time, please attach log or screenshot

#over-programming